# Access: Simplify sql-query: multiple IIFs

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

I got a table with a date-column and a column like this:

```
Column
01-00-00-00
01-02-00-00
03-06-00-00
05-13-00-00
....
```

What I want to do: Find out how many entries start with "01","02","03",... for every day.
 Therefore I need to first substract the first 2 characters, count them and group by the date.

I have a code that works fine, but needs really long. Do you have an idea for a more simple query?

```
    SELECT
      Date,
      sum(IIF(Platz='03',1,0)) as Gang_03,
      sum(IIF(Platz='04',1,0)) as Gang_04,
      sum(IIF(Platz='05',1,0)) as Gang_05,
      sum(IIF(Platz='06',1,0)) as Gang_06,
      sum(IIF(Platz='07',1,0)) as Gang_07,
      sum(IIF(Platz='08',1,0)) as Gang_08,
      sum(IIF(Platz='09',1,0)) as Gang_09,
      sum(IIF(Platz='10',1,0)) as Gang_10,
      sum(IIF(Platz='11',1,0)) as Gang_11,
      sum(IIF(Platz='12',1,0)) as Gang_12,
      sum(IIF(Platz='13',1,0)) as Gang_13,
      sum(IIF(Platz='14',1,0)) as Gang_14,
      sum(IIF(Platz='15',1,0)) as Gang_15,
      sum(IIF(Platz='16',1,0)) as Gang_16,
      sum(IIF(Platz='17',1,0)) as Gang_17,
      sum(IIF(Platz='18',1,0)) as Gang_18,
      sum(IIF(Platz='19',1,0)) as Gang_19,
      sum(IIF(Platz='20',1,0)) as Gang_20
    FROM
      (
      SELECT
            time_neu as Date,
            LEFT(Platz_von,2) as Platz
      FROM
            00_Gesamt_Pickauf
      )
    GROUP BY
      Date
```

Comment: Look at [`CROSSTAB`](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/crosstab_queries.html) queries

Comment: Agreed.  This sounds like you need some kind of pivot or crosstab query.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, you were right!